# mongodb command very slow

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have 3 documents like this:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("..."),
_details: {
    _session: ObjectId("example_1"),
},
{
_id: ObjectId("..."),
_details: {
    _session: ObjectId("example_1"),
},
{
_id: ObjectId("..."),
_details: {
    _session: ObjectId("example_2"),
}
```

And I'm trying to retrieve and group the `_details._session`'s ids. Expected output for the above example dataset would be:

```
['example_1', 'example_2']
```

I have tried the following Python script:

```
cursor = mycol.find({}, {"_details.session": 1})
sessions = []
for doc in cursor:
    if doc['_details']['_session'] not in sessions:
        sessions.append(doc['_details']['_session'])
```

Problem is that it takes around 1 minute for 500 documents.

Is there any way to speed up that command? I need it to run the fastest way possible.

Comment: I like [@gibbs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72240458/1409374), but I'm also wondering how long this takes: `cursor = mycol.find({}, {"_id": 0, "_details._session": 1}); sessions = set(doc['_details']['_session'] for doc in cursor)`

Comment: also very slow. 45s+ on 1.3k documents

Answer (score 0):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n-63ixhVkdn)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "uniqueSessions": {
        "$addToSet": "$_details._session"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You don't need to iterate through each document. You can achieve many things easily and efficiently using mongo aggregation framework.

You can add a `$project` stage to avoid `_id:null` in the output if it really bothers.

Comment: Hi, You missed to add the attempted command

Comment: The command still runs very slowly. I'm running the exact same command.

Comment: Can you update `explain` part of the command which says what index is used. How many documents? What's the amount of document being read?

Comment: sure, here is the output of the explain command: https://i.imgur.com/LZsu1UW.png

Comment: there are 1.3k documents

Comment: It should not be taking more time for just 1300 documents. Each details has only one session objects correct? How much time it takes now?

Comment: yes, each document has one session which can be the same for an arbitrary amount of documents. In this case out of 1.3k documents there are 6 unique session IDs, It takes around 30 seconds to complete.

Comment: only 1.3k docs in the collection? Is it the only stage you have? Do you see server logs?

Comment: no I dont have access to those. yes only stage

Comment: Explain results is as expected. There could be something wrong with the machines, volumes you have. I am not so sure about this. DBAdmin who has access to the cluster could help from server side

Comment: can you create a index on "_details._session" db.collection.createIndex( { "_details._session" :1} )refer https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/